# How to search github repositories by spoken language PyGithub Python

Tags: python, github, pygithub

The new Github trending page allows you to search repositories by spoken language e.g. English, I'm looking for the syntax to use with PyGithub.

Is it just:

```
g.search_repositories(query='spoken-language:english')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i don't know this, but, you can use `speech_recognition` library to convert audio to text, then you can use `pygithub` to search for repository.